# Getting worker name in Apache access log

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing

My **Apache httpd 2.2** is configured to load-balance two Tomcat servers.

How can I configure my access.log in Apache to capture worker name to which request is getting re-directed?

Answer (score 0):

Apache's access log cannot provide this information. As the name implies, it captures only clients' access data, irrespective of how these are processed internally. Your best bet will be setting the `JkLogLevel` to `debug` and checking the **JkLogFile** for the desired routing information (assuming you use `mod_jk`, see [Logging](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html#Logging)).